# visual studio code cannot find a program to debug node js

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have started a new tiny project.

1. I installed express.
2. Have www folder
3. have index.html file with this

   my local server

   ## server working

   just put your html,css, js files here and it work on your own local nodejs server
4. have server.js

   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();

   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));

   app.listen('3000');
   console.log('working on 3000');

On VS code, while running unity C# and pressing F5 is requested to select environment.

in JS I immediately get an error "cannot find program to debug", as well as when I press ctrl+F5 (run without debugging).

I see that here someone asked a similar question regarding python, but wasn't answered either.
[VSC debugger not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471203/vsc-debugger-not-working)

help anyone?

Comment: And [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging) was absolutely no help at all?

Comment: not sure i understand what they want from me there

Comment: this: _what they want from me there_.  Your answer is on the referenced page. They want you to read and follow instructions based upon the configuration you can't get to work.

Answer (score -1):

Ok let me try to help you
I was also stuck at the same problem.
Way I sort it =>
go to the launch.json file can edit the filename.js in configuration (I think that the filename which is debugging is not write)
Eg : I am debugging app.js (My configuration are::::)

> launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [


    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js"
    }
]``
```

}

If answer is helpful please vote my answer